# Send/Update reactor Mono Object to different attributes of a Flux.concat()

Tags: java, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, flux

I have a `Flux.concat()` operation which takes 3 checks like this:

```
public Mono<Boolean> checkSleep(Student std) 
{

Flux.concat(isHealthy(std), isWealthy(std, sleep), isWise(std, sleep))

.filter(result -> !result)
            .next()
            .flatMap(result -> Mono.just(false)) //returns false if any one is false
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(true)); // returns true if all are true

}
```

each of this methods has a common **external api call** `extService.getSleep(Student std)` to get **Sleep Object** `Mono<Sleep>` for its flow.

I want to call `extService.getSleep(Student std)` only once in the entire flow,

ideally in the first check `isHealthy(std)` and pass the object `Mono<Sleep>` to the next 2 checks as well.

I am not understanding how to make this call as `Flux.concat` does not allow a `Mono` to be added in the prefix.

Each of the checks have similar body like this:

```
Mono<Boolean> isHealthy(Student std) 
  {
    
    return Mono.just(std)
                 .flatMap(std->extService.getSleep(std)).map(sleep-> sleep.isValid()); 
  }
```

in the next check I want to pass `sleep` object from previous method,

`isWealthy(Student std, Sleep sleep)`
I do not want to call `extService.getSleep(std))` once again,

I thought of creating a variable outside these 3 methods and update it when the api returns a something,

it throws error saying `"Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final"`

Let me know if there is a better way to handle this scenario.

I am new to reactive spring programming, any help is appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line of thinking was not far off!

Whenever you need to "reach outside" a publisher, consider using `AtomicBoolean`, `AtomicInteger`, etc. or the parameterized `AtomicReference` to get around the final or effectively final compiler warning. However, it should be noted that asynchronous operations like `flatMap` may not have the correct value when they get the wrapped values from these, so it's best to get around the problem in a different way.

Fortunately, Reactor has a myriad of useful methods on its publishers!

If I understand correctly, the `checkSleep` function should resolve to true if all three of `isHealthy`, `isWealthy` and `isWise` also resolve to true - false if even one of them resolve to false.

I have created a simple simulation of this scenario:

```java
private Mono<Boolean> checkSleep(Student std) {
    return getSleep(std)
        .flatMapMany(sleep -> Flux.merge(isHealthy(std, sleep), isWealthy(std, sleep), isWise(std, sleep)))
        .all(result -> result);
}

private Mono<Sleep> getSleep(Student std) {
    return Mono.just(new Sleep(8));
}

private Mono<Boolean> isHealthy(Student std, Sleep sleep) {
    return Mono.just(true);
}

private Mono<Boolean> isWealthy(Student std, Sleep sleep) {
    return Mono.just(true);
}

private Mono<Boolean> isWise(Student std, Sleep sleep) {
    return Mono.just(true);
}
```

This way, getSleep is only called once, and is used to flat map the emitted value into the three booleans you're looking for. The `Flux::all` method then ensures that the returned Mono will wrap true only if all three inners have emitted true.

Another thing to note is that I've replaced `Flux::concat` with `Flux::merge`. The former goes sequentially, subscribing, waiting for result, then repeat. These three publishers seem to be independent of one another, so replacing concat with merge allows all three to be subscribed to at the same time, thereby reducing time wasted with waiting.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, may be there is quite a lot of difference in coding style when coming from a non reactive background to a reactive form of coding, in Rx it is more on combining the objets and flatMapping them in step by step manner, whereas in non-Rx you pass 1 object to different methods, and get the result and collaborate it. Anyway thanks for the answer, I am now slowly able to understand this way of coding with the help of the SOF  community.

Comment: @MohammedIdris yeah, it takes some getting used to, that's for sure!